# Any good resource for doing End to End Testing in .Net?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, integration-testing, bdd

I have been trying to adopt TDD and more specifically BDD. I know all the fancy terms, I know what should be done but I don't have any guidance/person to assist me. Its like learning to drive without an instructor and you don't know if you are shifting the gears properly etc :)

I have just read the book Growing Object-Oriented Software Guided By Tests by Steve Freeman and Nat Pryce and although it is an excellent book and I grasped a lot of concepts,  but the examples are written in Java and too hard for me. I being a .Net guy skipped through most of the code as it was more of a noise for me.

I was hoping there would be some equivalent book/material for a .Net guy. I would prefer if it uses ASP.Net MVC.

If there is any book out there that shows how to build a real world app using these techniques rather then just a calculator example; kindly do share it with me.

I will be grateful.

Thanks

Comment: Don't see code as noise just because it's in another language. Especially Java. The syntax is very similar to C# and shouldn't be too hard to understand.

Comment: You are quite right Daniel, but as a person who don't know tools like Spring, Window Licker etc; I found myself trying to understand which part of the code were relevant and which were not. I term noise as the code that is specific to macking framework, code runner etc. Its not easy to read code page to page top to bottom written in your favoured language :) not to mention a language and set of tools you have no idea about.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31837/best-books-about-tdd (check the accepted answer, refers to **great** books, one of them C#.

Comment: Every tool that is used in the GOOS book is explained in the beginning. I would expect every programmer, especially C# guys, to understand all the code in the book. Get yourself a free java IDE like Eclipse or NetBeans and get all the tools described in the book and do the code examples yourself. If you call yourself a programmer you should be able to pull this off...

Comment: I followed the GOOS book while implementing a solution in C# and used TestStack.White as a UI runner for my WPF app. It's on Nuget.